# Magento 2.4.5 when I try to call Soap API programmatically, then I get an error

Tags: magento2, php, api, soap-api-v2, soap-api

Error :  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://127.0.0.1/m245/api/v2_soap/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://127.0.0.1/m245/api/v2_soap/?wsdl"

**Here is code:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;


require '../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


try {

        $apisoap_v2_url = 'https://127.0.0.1/m245/api/v2_soap/?wsdl';
        $username = 'zwo4d9e6ulj48oy769kzp2zliftbbox4';
        $password = 'geco6v4yebn0xi06ataoaj7vmjejj8fu';
 
    
        if ($apisoap_v2_url && $username && $password) {
       
            $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
            $resource1 = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
            $collection = $resource1->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)
                ->load();

            $skus = array();

            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                $skus[] = $product->getSku();   
            }
            

            $proxy = new \SoapClient($apisoap_v2_url); 
            $sessionId = $proxy->login($username, $password); 
            $result = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemList($sessionId, $skus);

            var_dump($result);

}

}catch (\Exception $e){
    echo "****** Exception Throw ************* \n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . " \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why not able to give a response to the request, because it was not able to verify `SSL Certificates` enabled on the local site.

The way you can resolved it was to allow self signed `SSL verification`:

```
$opts = [
    'http' =>
     [
         'header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token
        ],
'ssl' => [
    'allow_self_signed' => true , 
    'verify_peer' => false, 
    'verify_peer_name' => false]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```